# Given a DB Instance how can I add SQL code into my database?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I just started using AWS and created a DB Instance. I expected a option to modify its contents/structures of the sql tables but couldn't find anything

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If it was SQL Server, you would uses SQL Server Management Studio to attach to the database and modify it just like you would locally - for MySQL you would need to use the equivalent UI Tool and attach to the DB and do the same.